# Secondary display connected to laptop not full screen or out of range

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a laptop name [DELL Inspiron 5577](https://www.amazon.in/Dell-Inspiron-5577-15-6-inch-i5-7300HQ/dp/B0749GG1V6) Display resolution: 1920*1080

I have an old monitor name [LG Flatron E1942C](https://www.lg.com/hk_en/monitor/lg-E1942C) Display resolution: 1366*768

Now I want to connect this monitor with my laptop to make an **extended display**. When I connect to this monitor through (HDMI -> VDI), I am having 2 kinds of issues.

Issue number 1: The display is not full screen or as expected. I am attaching a photo of how the display is. Please see it.[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrPHD.jpg)

Issue number 2: When I try to play around with different kinds of resolutions with Windows display manager or intel dedicated GPU software, it goes 67.4khz/60hz signal out of range.

I updated my drivers and did anything I found on googling. My laptop display is top-notch. I can see Rick Sanchez doing all the small movements but my extended monitor display is like, "Nope, I'm not gonna let you do it so easily".

Please help someone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your monitor has only a VGA input, so I'm assuming that "VDI" is a typo for [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector#/media/File:Vga-cable.jpg), not [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#/media/File:Dvi-cable.jpg).

The image is not positioned correctly, but the scale appears to be about right. This happens only with analog connections such as VGA and is caused by timing offsets being off (*very* off in your case). Use monitor's on-screen menu to adjust it. According to the [manual](https://www.lg.com/hk_en/support/product/lg-E1942C-BN) this setting is on the 3rd tab (*horizontal* and *vertical* controls).

Comment: I scaled it vertically and set the mode from original to wide. It is now as I want this to be :)
Also, I set it to 1366*768 from recommended 12xx something and changed it from maintaining aspect ratio to stretch. Sir there are little dots appearing and disappearing on the screen and the icon etc are quite big. Can I do something about this or this is a resolution issue?

Comment: Size of things on the screen depends on resolution and scaling. Resolution should be set to screen's native resolution for best results, but in Windows 10 you can set scaling individually for each screen. The laptop is probably using scaling over 100%, so you could try lowering it for the external display in _Display settings_. As for little dots, I'm not sure what it is that you're seeing, but VGA is just not good and some anomalies are to be expected (although I'm surprised that they're visible at such low resolution). You could try changing the cable to a better quality one.

Comment: You mean the cable that I am using from my Laptop(HDMI) then the converter(HDMI TO VGA) and then to my monitor? Moving dots everywhere. Very little. I set it to native resolution 1366*768 but like my mouse pointer is quite cool on my laptop and a bit bulky on my secondary display. Scale starts from 100-500 and my laptop is set to 125% and this one to 100%.

Comment: You can't go below 100%, so that's the best you can do. It's a rather large display for that resolution. The cable must have an active adapter inside it (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1601220) for explanation what it means) and if it's poor quality, it could introduce some noise too.

Comment: Thank you, sir and I understand that there is an active conversion from my HDMI to VGA and I need a good quality converter to actually make the quality better. Could you suggest me one from your vast experience on Amazon or something?

Comment: Frankly I've never needed one. Go by the reviews I guess, and be careful, sometimes two identically looking products have completely different parts inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116603/discussion-between-shobhit-tewari-and-gronostaj).